# Spring MVC Diffrence between Path & Variable in @RequestMapping Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, request-mapping

I would like to know what are the differences between `Path` and `Variable` in Spring MVC in the `Controller` class.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
@RequestMapping(path = "/home")
```

Base on the Spring Documentation [Spring 5 Annotation Type RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) the path is an alias for value, and the value is the alias for the path.
I would like to know this 3 RequestMapping definitions and difference.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between @RequestMapping("/home") and @RequestMapping(value = "/home").But if you want to add some other parameter then you have to use,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/home/{ABC}", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
```

because if write,

```
@GetMapping("/getTodayActivity/{millis}", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
```

then it will compile error, so only want to use more parameter then you have to use "value"

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) there is no difference between `@RequestMapping("/home")` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")` when you are using to class level or method level.

However, you can use pass more than one variable with this usage `@RequestMapping(value={"/method1","/method1/second"})`

Comment: Reference should be official document or from reliable and wellknown source

Comment: Thanks. Could I need to update my answer because actually spring docs also says same thing ?  This is an alias for path(). For example @RequestMapping("/foo") is equivalent to @RequestMapping(path="/foo").

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between `@RequestMapping("/home")` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")`. You can quickly use the former if there's only one mapping, and latter if there are multiple URLs that are being mapped to same place, for example, `@RequestMapping(value={"/home","/home2","/home2/home3"})`

Similarly, the [path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) and [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--) are also same. If you look at their definitions, they are basically alias of each other:

definition of *value*:

```
@AliasFor(value="path")
public abstract java.lang.String[] value
    ...
```

definition of *path*:

```
@AliasFor(value="value")
public abstract java.lang.String[] path
    ...
```

As for all the definitions, you can always visit [the official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).